Strange behavior with player positions synchronization in VR multiplayer app
I'm developing a VR multiplayer application using Netcode for GameObjects with two Quest headsets, and I'm running into a weird synchronization issue.
Current behavior:

Headset 1 can see its own position correctly
Headset 2 can see Headset 1's position
BUT: Headset 2 cannot see its own position
AND: Headset 1 cannot see Headset 2's position

The strange part:

Basic object synchronization works perfectly (when Headset 2 moves a cube, Headset 1 sees it and vice versa)
Debug info always shows only 1 player (Player 1)
Even on Headset 2, it shows "Total Players: 1" and "List of IDs: 0" (Player 1's ID)

My setup:

NetworkObject component on XR Origin (XR Rig) with following settings:

Synchronize Transform ✓
Active Scene Synchronization ✓
Scene Migration Synchronization ✓
Spawn With Observer ✓
Auto Object Parent Sync ✓


NetworkedHeadTracker script attached with NetworkVariable

I'm trying to display each player's position in a text UI element at the top of the screen. Despite the object synchronization working fine, it seems like there's an issue with player discovery or registration.
Has anyone encountered something similar? Any ideas what might be causing this or how to fix it?
Here is how my code look like (2 files (100 lines of code in total))
NetworkedHeadTracker.cs
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class NetworkedHeadTracker : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private Transform mainCamera;
    private Transform spatialAnchor;
    
    public NetworkVariable<Vector3> networkHeadPosition = new NetworkVariable<Vector3>();
    private static readonly Dictionary<ulong, NetworkedHeadTracker> allPlayers = new Dictionary<ulong, NetworkedHeadTracker>();
    public static IReadOnlyDictionary<ulong, NetworkedHeadTracker> AllPlayers => allPlayers;

    private void Awake()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main?.transform;
        spatialAnchor = GameObject.Find("[BuildingBlock] Shared Spatial Anchor Core")?.transform;
    }

    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        if (!allPlayers.ContainsKey(OwnerClientId))
        {
            allPlayers[OwnerClientId] = this;
        }
    }

    public override void OnNetworkDespawn()
    {
        allPlayers.Remove(OwnerClientId);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (IsSpawned && IsOwner && mainCamera != null && spatialAnchor != null)
        {
            networkHeadPosition.Value = spatialAnchor.InverseTransformPoint(mainCamera.position);
        }
    }

    public Vector3 GetWorldPosition()
    {
        return spatialAnchor != null ? spatialAnchor.TransformPoint(networkHeadPosition.Value) : networkHeadPosition.Value;
    }
}

HeadPositionHUD.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Linq;
using TMPro;
public class HeadPositionHUD : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI hudText;
    public float updateInterval = 0.5f;
    private float timer;
    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer >= updateInterval)
        {
            UpdateHUD();
            timer = 0;
        }
    }
    void UpdateHUD()
    {
        if (!NetworkManager.Singleton.IsClient) return;
        string hudContent = "";
        // Debug info at the top
        hudContent += $"=== DEBUG INFO ===\n";
        hudContent += $"My Local ID: {NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId}\n";
        hudContent += $"Total number of players: {NetworkedHeadTracker.AllPlayers.Count}\n";
        hudContent += $"List of IDs: {string.Join(", ", NetworkedHeadTracker.AllPlayers.Keys)}\n";
        hudContent += "================\n\n";
        foreach (var player in NetworkedHeadTracker.AllPlayers.OrderBy(p => p.Key))
        {
            if (player.Value == null)
            {
                hudContent += $"Player {player.Key}: null\n";
                continue;
            }
            Vector3 worldPosition = player.Value.GetWorldPosition();
            if (player.Key == NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId)
            {
                hudContent += $"My position (ID: {player.Key}):\n";
                hudContent += $"X: {worldPosition.x:F2}, Y: {worldPosition.y:F2}, Z: {worldPosition.z:F2}\n\n";
            }
            else
            {
                hudContent += $"Other player (ID: {player.Key}):\n";
                hudContent += $"X: {worldPosition.x:F2}, Y: {worldPosition.y:F2}, Z: {worldPosition.z:F2}\n\n";
            }
        }
        hudText.text = hudContent;
    }
}


probably unrelated sidenote regarding spatialAnchor = GameObject.Find("[BuildingBlock] Shared Spatial Anchor Core")?.transform; a) instead of that very long name I would rather simply attach a dedicated component script with the sole purpose of using FindAnyObjectByType on it (avoids issues due to hardcoded strings) ... and b) ? does not work for UnityEngine.Object
